# How do you create a Keynote-like interface in Cocoa and IB?

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

the app I want to create will have an interface very like Keynote, with a list of pages on the left and one page in full on the right. These kinds of interfaces are very common yet I don't know how to do them in Interface Builder.

Are there any ready-made components? Apple doesn't offer any, afaik. Or does every developer recreate this from scratch?

I only need a general idea or tutorial, no finished code.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to a scrollable list of same-size thumbnails, use NSCollectionView / NSCollectionViewItem. Should be very easy: the item would just display a thumbnail image based on your document editor view's current state. In 10.6, it got some drag and drop support, if I remember correctly from WWDC '09, so you can drag-reorder your pages this way, too.

For the editor side, the collection view would only work if all your pages are the same size, as it doesn't allow for variable-sized items. If all your "pages" are the same size, though, the collection view should actually work for this too.

Comment: Thank you. And how do I set up the whole window and frame? Like a source list in iTunes with a plus button at the bottom, a resize widget somewhere (so you don't have to hit the small vertical line), etc...

Comment: There are no built-in controls to do that. Google "BWToolkit" - I believe there are ready-made controls for the "split view with a grip and control bar." In the future, you should consider posting things like this as individual questions on SO. Keep them focused and pointed so it's easier to give focused and pointed answers.